# Find folders containing a specific pattern of files but nothing else

Tags: files

If I want to search for all folders containing only *.srt files but nothing else in the folder, how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Look for directories containing files named `*.srt`, then look for directories containing files or directories *not* named `*.srt`, and only keep directories unique to the first list:

```
comm -23 \
<(find . -type f -name \*.srt -printf '%h\n' | sort -u) \
<(find . ! -name \*.srt -printf '%h\n' | sort -u)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `find` and the `bash` shell: For each directory, see if there are any filenames matching `*.srt`.  If there are, see if the number of such names is the same as what matches `*`.  If that's the case, print the directory path:

```bsh
find . -type d -exec bash -O nullglob -c '
    for dirpath do
        list1=( "$dirpath"/*.srt )
        if [[ ${#list1[@]} -gt 0 ]]; then
            list2=( "$dirpath"/* )
            if [[ ${#list1[@]} -eq ${#list2[@]} ]]; then
                printf "%s\n" "$dirpath"
            fi
        fi
    done' bash {} +
```

or, without that deep nesting in the in-line `bash -c` script:

```bsh
find . -type d -exec bash -O nullglob -c '
    for dirpath do
        list1=( "$dirpath"/*.srt )
        [[ ${#list1[@]} -eq 0 ]] && continue

        list2=( "$dirpath"/* )
        [[ ${#list1[@]} -ne ${#list2[@]} ]] && continue

        printf "%s\n" "$dirpath"
    done' bash {} +
```

Using an extended globbing pattern to match the names not matching `*.srt` instead of comparing the length of two lists (saves one array).  Also use list of positional parameters to save a tiny bit on typing:

```bsh
find . -type d -exec bash -O extglob -O nullglob -c '
    for dirpath do
        set -- "$dirpath"/*.srt
        [[ $# -eq 0 ]] && continue

        set -- "$dirpath"/!(*.srt)
        [[ $# -ne 0 ]] && continue

        printf "%s\n" "$dirpath"
    done' bash {} +
```